# How to apply regex pattern for mobile numbers and landline numbers

Tags: android, regex, string

I want to apply a regex pattern to identify all mobile numbers and landline numbers for countries like US, UK and India.
Currently i am using the following pattern

> (?:+\s*\d{2}[\s-]*)?(?:\d[-\s]*){10}

Unfortunately, it is only recognizing `10` digits numbers without country code. Also, if anyone knows of a good regex to identify landline numbers, kindly let me know.

Comment: There are many many examples of this, one of the toughest regexes to get right (along with email).  Just Google it.  Google should always be your first choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(([^\.\-\,a-wy-z]([\(]?(\+|[x])?\d+[\)]?)?[\s\.\-\,]?([\(]?\d+[\)]?)?[\s\.\-\,]?(\d+[\s\.\-\,]?)+[^\.\-\,a-z])|((\+|[x])?\d+))$
```

This should match most phone numbers you are looking for.

**Matches**

```
201-654-5932
201 654 5932
(201)-654-5932
201.654.5932
X201.654.5932
+1 201.654.5932
1.123.123.123
020 1234 5678
02-9323-1234
(02) 9323 1234
1-561-555-1212
12345-1234
(913) 451-6461
(+447222)555555
+44 7222 555 555
+91-98-44111112
+91-9844111112
+44(7222)555555
1(240) 652-5009
(0833)1234567-8888
+974-584-5656
+44 07222 555555
1.2123644567
1-(212)-123 4567
1212-364,4321
0-212364345
(658)154-1122
123131312312
875 (489 1568)
(+91)(240) 652-5009
```

**Non-Matches**

```
+()-
(+)-,.
493 -- 3227341
240/752-5009
(+91)(240)(876867) 652-5009
+974-5dadad32d84-5656
++44 07222 555555
0-234.567/8912
0212\345/6789
652-5009.
652-5009-
652-5009,
.652-5009
-652-5009
,652-5009
1-800-ALPHNUM
a-12-3
(658 154 1122
658 154 1122)
```

Source: http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2693

Comment: Thanks for the answer furnished. Is there any possible ways to identify landline and mobile numbers.

Comment: The above pattern is not working when i tried to apply regex pattern to get the phone numbers from the addresses...